# cp from different directory to one directory certain files

Tags: cp

I want to do the following.

I want to copy from a remote FTP server every day certain files.
This FTP directory is mounted.
Every day a directory is created and within that directory I need 3 files of the 5

```
dir1
dir2
dir3
```

I want to copy every day the files with certain extensions  to dir999

```
cp */*.img /dir999
```

But will that copy every day all files again ? as its a lot i only want to do the changes.

Comment: Hi, i want this automated, so that i can do it in a crontab and every day download only the new files from the new directories that were created.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `rsync`.  There are dozens of questions like this here so you might want to examine them for a suitable duplicate rather than posting a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Many implementations of `cp` like FreeBSD, GNU and MacOS have an option `-n` to skip existing files. So with

```
cp -n */*.img /dir999
```

you will only copy new files. Note that changed files won't get updated in the destination directory. If you want this, you'd need a different solution.

Comment: stupid me, yes that is what i needed. Thank you.

Comment: @mamoman there are no stupid people here :-) If this answer works for you please remember to accept it with the tick mark in the corner.